# How do I start from a specified value in an array?

Tags: java

For example:

```
String[] someArray = {null, "I want to start from here", "other element", "other element"};

for(int i = 1; i < someArray.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(someArray[i]);
}
```

Is there way to set the inital index of an array other than setting the first element to null?

In the for loop, I want to set `i = 1`.

Comment: What's your goal in doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  If it's something like having a user type 1 to refer to the first item, just subtract 1.

Comment: I don't know Java, but if there is a way (which I doubt), don't do it.

Comment: okay, maybe its really not the best way...changed decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set the initial index of an array: it still has a 1st (index 0) element, it just happens to be `null` in your case. You can always start iterating from whatever index you want, but you'll be wasting space.

You could always make your own class...

```
class WeirdIndexArray<T> {
    private final T[] internalArray;
    public final int firstIndex;
    public final int indexBound;
    public WeirdIndexArray( int firstIndex, int size ){
        internalArray = new T[size];
        this.firstIndex = firstIndex;
        indexBound = firstIndex+size;
    }
    public void set( int index, T item ){ internalArray[index-firstIndex] = item; }
    public T get( int index ){ return internalArray[index-firstIndex]; }
}
```

And use it...

```
WeirdIndexArray<String> array = new WeirdIndexArray<>(1,3);

for( int i=1; i<array.indexBound; i++ )
    array.set(i,"This is item "+i);
```

But **why** would you need that in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

The way to iterate over elements when you wish to start at a different element is to change the starting index.

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    // Iteration operation
}
```

`i` is the only thing you concern yourself with, should you wish to start in a spot different than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the first element equal to null has nothing to do with the way you iterate over an array with a for loop.

You could set it to anything and you can start your for loop with anything.

However, it makes no sense to decide you don't like zero based indexing.

That's how all programming languages work (as far as I know).